# I need to redirect an entire subdirectory in WordPress to the homepage - is this correct?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

To redirect ALL the pages within a subdirectory I can use this .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

My question is: can I simply use this exactly as prescribed? Would I need to edit it to specifically work on WordPress?

Also! Where should I place it - at the very top or anywhere will do in the .htaccess file?

Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^subfolder http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
> ```

Strictly speaking this redirects any URLs that start `/subfolder`, including URLs of the form `/subfolderfoo` and `/subfolderbar` which obviously don't fall "within the subdirectory". And this is regardless of whether "subfolder" is a physical *subdirectory* on the filesystem or an entirely virtual (WordPress) URL-path. (If it was a physical subdirectory then you could create another `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory instead and "simplify" the rule.)

To redirect `/subfolder` and only URLs that are contained within that URL-path segment, eg. `/subfolder/foo` and `/subfolder/bar`, but not `/subfolderfoo` etc. then you should use the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder($|/) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

> Would I need to edit it to specifically work on WordPress?

This will work on WordPress as it would on any other Apache website.

However, it *must* go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller. ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. Otherwise, if `/subfolder` is a virtual URL-path, the directive will never be processed (since the request would be routed to the WordPress front-controller and processing stops).

You should test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.